# Export my Tableau parameter list

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

I've "hand crafted" (started with over 500 then lots of deletes)  a parameter list of about 100 string items in Tableau. Anyone know a way to  export this list so I can use it in my python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting requirement. Parameters are actually saved in the XML of the workbook. You should be able to open the workbook .twb in a text editor and extract the values.It will look something like this

If you are working with a .twbx, you would need to unzip it first and then open the .twb.

Keep well

Comment: Clever suggestion! Thank you!!